# Trying to move files from one google drive folder to another using google sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Current Google Sheets script below, where column A is the file address and column B is the folder address for the file to move to.

```
function moveFile(fileId, destFolderId) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  try {
    // Get the file by its ID
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

    // Get the destination folder by its ID
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId);

    // Move the file to the destination folder
    folder.createFile(file.getBlob());
    file.setTrashed(true);

    ui.alert('File moved successfully: ' + fileId);
  } catch (error) {
    ui.alert('Error moving file ' + fileId + ': ' + error.toString());
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  // Check if the edit occurred in columns A and B
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 || range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var fileId = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
    var destFolderId = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).getValue();

    // Ensure both File ID and Destination Folder ID are provided
    if (fileId && destFolderId) {
      moveFile(fileId, destFolderId);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this I get these error;

**Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.
moveFile    @ Code.gs:2**

**Error moving file [file path] Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)**

I have added the required permissions to the appsscript.json , below;

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "DriveActivity",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "driveactivity"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "DriveLabels",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drivelabels"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "AdSense",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "adsense"
      }
    ]
 },
 "oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
 ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
  "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
  "access": "MYSELF"
 }
}
```

Comment: When you say "when I run this", what do you mean?

Comment: onEdit is a simple trigger it can not do a lot  of things that require permissions.  Try using an installable trigger

Comment: I have the script set to run when Coulmn A (file path) and B (destination folder path) are updated in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function moveFile(fileId, destFolderId) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  try {
    // Get the file by its ID
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId);
    folder.createFile(file.getBlob());
    file.setTrashed(true);
    ui.alert('File moved successfully: ' + fileId);
  } catch (error) {
    ui.alert('Error moving file ' + fileId + ': ' + error.toString());
  }
}


function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet0" &&  e.range.columnStart < 3 ) {
    e.source.toast("Gate")
    const [fileId,destFolderId] = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,2).getValues().flat();
    if (fileId && destFolderId) {
      moveFile(fileId, destFolderId);
    }
  }
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: When I add that, I get the error; Error moving file [object Object]: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.

Comment: also, on the script editor I get error; TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

Comment: I didn't have a complete declaration in my assignment in the onEdit function.  It's working now

Answer (score 0):

Code.gs below...

```
 function moveFiles() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A:B").getValues();
  var successCount = 0;
  var failureCount = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var fileId = data[i][0]; // File ID from column A
    var destFolderId = data[i][1]; // Destination Folder ID from column B

    if (fileId && destFolderId) {
      try {
        // Get the file by its ID
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

        // Get the destination folder by its ID
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId);

        // Move the file to the destination folder
        file.moveTo(folder);
        successCount++;
      } catch (error) {
        failureCount++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (successCount > 0) {
    ui.alert('Files moved successfully: ' + successCount + ' files.');
  }

  if (failureCount > 0) {
    ui.alert('Failed to move ' + failureCount + ' files. Check for errors.');
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Move Files', 'moveFiles')
    .addToUi();
}
```

appsscript.json below

> 

```
    {   "timeZone": "America/New_York",   "dependencies": {
>     "enabledAdvancedServices": [
>       {
>         "userSymbol": "Drive",
>         "version": "v2",
>         "serviceId": "drive"
>       },
>       {
>         "userSymbol": "DriveActivity",
>         "version": "v2",
>         "serviceId": "driveactivity"
>       },
>       {
>         "userSymbol": "Sheets",
>         "version": "v4",
>         "serviceId": "sheets"
>       },
>       {
>         "userSymbol": "DriveLabels",
>         "version": "v2",
>         "serviceId": "drivelabels"
>       },
>       {
>         "userSymbol": "AdSense",
>         "version": "v2",
>         "serviceId": "adsense"
>       }
>     ]  },  "oauthScopes": [   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
> ],   "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",   "runtimeVersion": "V8",  
> "webapp": {   "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",   "access": "MYSELF"  } }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**